# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        Iterator itr = null;
        StringBuffer sb = null;
        Entry entry = null;
        String key = null;
        String val = null;

        map.put("1", "Rakesh");
        map.put("2", "Amal");
        map.put("3", "Nithish");

        itr = map.keySet().iterator();
        sb = new StringBuffer();

        while(itr != null && itr.hasNext()) {
            try {
                entry = (Entry) itr.next();
                key = (String) entry.getKey();
                val = (String) entry.getValue();
                System.out.println(key);
                System.out.println(val);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }






java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
    at com.sixdee.prepaidwork.MapZ.main(MapZ.java:38)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
    at com.sixdee.prepaidwork.MapZ.main(MapZ.java:38)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
    at com.sixdee.prepaidwork.MapZ.main(MapZ.java:38)
```

Comment: If you avoid using the raw `Entry` and `Iterator` types, you'll get the appropriate error at *compile* time...

Comment: BTW, you can really simplify the iteration, by using enhanced for loop. And also, Java is not C. You don't need to declare the variables  all at one place. You can declare them as you need them.

Answer (score 10):

```
itr = map.keySet().iterator();
```

should be

```
itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

...as you would have noticed if you'd used generics properly throughout your program, by giving `itr` type `Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>>` and `entry` type `Map.Entry<String, String>`.